# How to use full screen width in Google Docs

Tags: google-docs

How can I use the full screen width in Google Docs? Since the latest revision, it appears that a fixed-width display is all that's available. If I'm not printing, I have no reason to see a paper-size fixed-width view.

Comment: I totally agree that they should have a way to have a non-tree-killing writing, but I've hopefully given you an answer for the closest you can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New option to set full width, set Text Width to Full.

You can also enable the pageless feature.

Google Docs has a new "Pageless" page setup, available in the Google Docs editor top menu > File > Page setup > select "Pageless" at the top of the built-in window.

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 15):

There isn't a way to make a document full screen, but you can get close.

Go to *File* → *Page Setup* and set it up like the following.

- Change Portrait to Landscape
- Change Margins to 0
- Change Paper size to A3

[image: Google Document Page Setup Menu]

Comment: Good find! Not perfect, but much better.

Comment: A3 seems too big, Using A4 worked better for me.

Answer (score 7):

Not sure when this happened, but today I discovered Docs now has a `fit` option under the `Zoom` drop-down menu...

[image]

..which works exactly like you want!
[image]

Comment: This is technically an upwards zoom http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/70788/10579 so stuff like font shape, table borders, images, etc [are pixelated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixelation) and looks horrible.

Comment: "Horrible" is in the eye of the beholder. For me this method is preferable because it will print on 8.5x11 paper without any extra steps. I can deal with slightly less crisp fonts.

Comment: any idea how to set that by default?

Comment: not sure how horrible is horrible, but I guess if you're making google docs that you're going to eventually print... then definitely don't modify your page size!

Answer (score 2):

Google Docs has a new "Pageless" page setup, available in the Google Docs editor top menu > File > Page setup > select "Pageless" at the top of the built-in window.

Unfortunately it's still stuck at the same fixed width, but it's a bit easier to resize the font size and zoom in.

Comment: After changing the Page Setup to pageless, go to View, "Text width" and set it to Full. That fixes the width issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have also been looking for a solution to this problem, and although it would be preferable to have a 'fit to width' option I have managed to find a reasonable fix on the mac at least. The pinch zoom function on a mac book pro (or View > Zoom in) will enable you to make your doc fill the screen. Presumably Chrome on windows also has a zoom in option.

Comment: I just tried it on my Chrome Browser. This solution is much better.

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to Dez's answer, if you need a better solution choose **Legal 8.5" × 14"** instead of **A3 11.69" × 16.54"**:

File → Page Setup

[image]

**Legal 8.5" × 14"** gives you the best width to height ratio (`1.64705882353` width per height) out of the 11 possible options:

[image]

Also, some has suggested "Fit Zooming":

[image]

But you **do not** want to do this because zooming will make the document look extremely ugly. The pixels will get muddled just like how images reek foulness when [zoomed upwards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixelation).

Answer (score 1):

Try these settings:

- Just once for all docs:

  - `View`: `Print layout`: unchecked
- For each doc:

  - `File`: `Page setup`:

    - `Orientation`: `Landscape`
    - `Paper size`: `Tabloid (11" x 17")` (or `Legal (8.5" x 14")` for 15" displays)
  - `Zoom`: `Fit` or `100%`, etc.

If the pragmatic goal is to maximize the usable width, the noted settings together contribute to this effect. If you're not sufficiently satisfied, you can decrease the margins.